# Running Jest on TypeScript tests in non-src folders of a React App

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have a react-app that I created using `create-react-app` with the `typescript` template.  As I understand it, the `src` folder is for code that will be part of the web app.  I'd like to include server code in the same project and so I place it in a separate folder `server` because this code should not be packed with with the rest of the front end.  The problem is that I want to add Jest tests for this code.  The react-script for testing doesn't support tests anywhere other than `src`, which is fine (it simply doesn't find them).  I can't override `roots` without "ejecting".  So I tried adding a new script in the `"scripts"` of `package.json`:

```
"test-server":"jest server"
```

The problem now is that `jest` cannot handle TypeScript syntax.  It gets a SyntaxError on the first place I used TypeScript.  I tried to add `ts-jest` as a `"preset"` but (1) it appears that React doesn't use `ts-jest` (it uses something else to parse TypeScript--perhaps babel?) and so it isn't installed already (2) `react-scripts` also doesn't like me fiddling with `"preset"`.  I could create a special config file just for server testing, but it seems crazy that I would need to install `ts-jest` just to run TypeScript tests outside of `src` when React is quite capable to doing that already, so it must have the capability already.

My guess is that there must be a way to create a configuration file that I can use in `"test-server"` to use the babel (?) way to run Jest on TypeScript, but I don't know babel well enough to know how to do this.  Surely, someone has already done this.  I can't be the only one that wants to run tests on server code in TypeScript in a React application.

**UPDATE** I tried the following configuration file and get further:

```
module.exports = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>/server'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$':
      '<rootDir>/node_modules/react-scripts/config/jest/babelTransform.js'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$',
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$',
  ],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
};
```

but it fails when a module I import (here "nanoid") uses module syntax:

```
   Details:

    .../node_modules/nanoid/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { randomFillSync } from 'crypto'
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import assert from 'assert';
      2 | import fs from 'fs/promises';
    > 3 | import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
        | ^
```

**UPDATE #2**: Well, I can't use nanoid in tests under `src` either.  So, it seems to be a more serious problem.  Maybe I can hack nanoid not to use the module syntax that upsets Jest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config file I gave in the update is sufficient to make things work.  The remaining problem was `nanoid`.  I found elsewhere that the current version of `nanoid` doesn't work with React/babel.  I reverted to version 3.3.4, and Jest now works with my server tests.

Comment: Does not work for me, I'm on nanoid 3.3.4 but still same problem. So something else must be able to cause this issue as well!